# About updating the UEFI /BIOS on an ASUS ROG MAXIMUS XIII HERO

Tags: bios, uefi, asus

I am having issues with games crashing and my computer randomly blue-screening. The following is the build:

[image: Build Details]

Not listed here is the PSU, which is 950 watts, windows and gfx drivers are up-to-date.

I have gotten some errors in the Event Viewer, and that led me to going into the UEFI/BIOS and disabling the PCIE power management option and that solved a good portion of the EV errors, specifically `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_4C01&SUBSYS_86941043&REV_01` that was popping in multiple times per minute.

I have also gotten a few errors regarding Intel's EC returning data when none was requested, though not nearly as many or as frequently as the above error.

After searching around, everything seems to point towards needing to update the UEFI/BIOS. However, on the [ASUS website](https://rog.asus.com/us/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-xiii-hero-model/helpdesk_bios/) for the board it lists an older version of the Intel ME driver, `15.0.45.2411V2`, and the latest one listed on [Intel's site](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/682431/intel-management-engine-drivers-for-windows-10-and-windows-11.html) is `16.0.285`.

Should I use the tools from the ASUS website or from Intel's?

Comment: What does the firmware have to do with Intel ME?

Comment: Good question; take a look at the ASUS website link and it says to do so. That would be a great question answered since I have not found anything definitive yet (other than them saying "to ensure optimized system settings")

Comment: How have you updated the BIOS and where did you get it from ?

Comment: I have not proceeded with the BIOS update yet. I have prepared the file, however, on a USB disk. It came from the ASUS website and I verified with two separate MD5 checkers for the ZIP and it checked out on both, just to be sure.

Comment: Always get the firmware (UEFI, BIOS isn't a thing since 2012) from the motherboard's manufacturer. Any other drivers/software typically can be obtained from the various chipset manufacturers. Unless otherwise specified you can use newer versions than the ones released by the motherboard's manufacturer because such releases tend to stop when they *de facto* end the support for the motherboard. My initial question is because you're probably confusing two different and independent things thus resulting in a nonsensical paragraph.

Comment: Assuming self build, did you bother take take any kind of ESD precautions? If not, then who knows what damage you have done.

Comment: You always use the software and drivers from the OEM, that is ASUS in this case. They will support specific versions. Using generic versions from another publisher may have unintended consequences.

Comment: @music2myear Indeed, but sometimes (or most of the times) the drivers from the motherboard's manufacturer are the same as generic and thiose can be updated with newer version published by the chipsets' manufacturers (e.g. Intel) when ASUS in this case strops supporting a given model. The only exceptions I've came across in decades are a few modified Realtek audio drivers. Firmware (BIOS/UEFI) of course, always from ASUS and nowhere else.